# How to change even list to odd list in racket/scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have the following code for even list:

```
(define (even xs)
    (cond
        ((null? xs) '())   
        ((eq? (cdr xs) '()) '()) 
        (else (cons (cadr xs) (even (cddr xs)))))) 
;(even-list   '(a b c d)) produces (b d)
```

How can I do the same for odd list that  produce (a c) if  (odd-list   '(a b c d)) is enetered.

Comment: You already know about `null?`– replace `(eq? (cdr xs) '())` with `(null? (cdr xs))`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you're asked to write this out fully, on your own. For that, do note that (in the code you provide) you're checking whether the `cdr` is empty list, because you're taking the `cadr` as your first element.

For odds, you don't need the `cadr`. The first element is at an odd position already.

But there's also a simple trick you could use.

Question: what effect does `(cons 1 xs)` have on the length of `xs`?